# Creating a mysql insert/update integrity trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following three fields in my database:

- name
- birth
- location
- composite_index

I want to set a unique constraint on these, so that the following is not allowed:

```
"David-20140101-NULL"
"David-20140101-NULL"
```

Because I want to count `NULL` as an actual value (like `''`), I cannot do `ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE KEY (name,birth,location)`. How would I add an `INSERT+UPDATE` trigger on the above to UPDATE the `compositive_index` helper field?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen ok, I added in the additional `composite_index` into the question. How would I then do it?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen cool -- can you post that as an answer and I'll accept it with the SQL.

Comment: You're trying to constrain the unconstrainable.  If this is what you want, you might just as easily make the location column `NOT NULL DEFAULT '-'` so that the marker for an unset location is automatically the value '-' rather than being NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are still no function based indexes in mysql, you will have to create a helper column (name eg `composite_index`) (which you can manage with a trigger). This helper column then has the unique index in place, full filling your requirements.

For this then to work you will have to create two triggers. An insert trigger and an before update trigger. These need to have a line in there as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER {unique triggername} AFTER INSERT ON {table}
BEGIN
 UPDATE {table} SET composite_index=CONCAT(yourvalues) WHERE id=new.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER {unique triggername} BEFORE UPDATE ON {table}
BEGIN
 UPDATE {table} SET composite_index=CONCAT({yourvalues}) WHERE id=new.id;
END;
```

In this {yourvalues} are the `new.{columnname}`

Plus you will have to add one unique index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_un_1 ON {table}(composite_index);
```

This index now ensures that a record can not be inserted as duplicate

You have to see if it needs to be before or after triggers:

- For the `update` the `before` will work and is best: That way the update is checked on uniqueness before the update is executed and fails fast when you have an uniqueness conflict;
- for `insert` I think it has to be an after trigger).